# how to create a button hyperlink while displaying into php

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I want button control to display instead of anchor tag, so that I am able to set some css to that button.

here what I tried:

```
if ($number >= 1) {
echo "<a href='pagination2.php?page=" . ($number - 1) . "'>Prev </a>";
}
```

but I want to display button instead of anchor tag.
How to do that?

Comment: I think you can do that with help of css.  And if you are using bootstrap then there is default class btn is present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<style>
.button {
  font: bold 15px Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #333344;
  padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
</style>



 if ($number >= 1) {
    echo "<a class ='button' href='pagination2.php?page=" . ($number - 1) .  "'>Prev </a>";
}
```

May this helps you. Css code need to add in style sheet file. If you want to learn bootstrap it is here [Bootstarp](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)

Answer (score 0):

Give a `class` to the `anchor` tag. And apply `CSS`

```css
a.button {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    -moz-appearance: button;
    appearance: button;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: initial;
}
```

```html
if ($number >= 1) {
   echo "<a href='pagination2.php?page=" . ($number - 1) . "' class="button">Prev </a>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a button instead of an anchor tag, use this

```
if ($number >= 1) {
echo "<button onclick='window.location=pagination2.php?page=" . ($number - 1) . "'>Prev</button>";
}
```

Then apply the CSS as you choose.

Answer (score 0):

> You can write like this

```
if ($number >= 1) {
    echo "<a href='pagination2.php?page=" . ($number - 1) . "'><button>Prev</button></a>";
}
```

in this you have no require to add any css

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer:

```
if ($number >= 1) {
    echo "<button onclick=\"location.href='"pagination2.php?page=" . ($number - 1) . "'\">Prev</button>";
}
```

If you don't already have a template, Bootstrap has some nice [breadcrumbs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#breadcrumbs) that might help you do what you want. Alternatively, you can add the class `.btn` (also from Bootstrap) to an `<a>` tag.

For a more in-depth description, you might want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-do-i-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link#2906586) question on Stack Overflow.